# transform scale acting weird on Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I've made a website using Bootstrap 3. Bootstrap 3 contains flat triangles as glyphicons. But the icons are to flat so I stretch them using my stretch class:

```
.stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(3,2); /* W3C */
    -webkit-transform: scale(3,2); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: scale(3,2); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: scale(3,2); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: scale(3,2); /* Opera */
}
```

it works great but if i'm using Safari 5 the icon looks weird.(sorry I cannot upload an image direct).
The sides of the triangle are a blurred:

[image]

the class of the glyphicon is:

```
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I already tried this in the body class:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the icons are to flat"?

Comment: @JakeTaylor the width of the traingles is to small, that's why I scale them.

Comment: This link may help you to solve your problem  **https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106**

Answer (score 0):

Blurry scaling is a bug in Safari: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27684

To work around this issue, you could try to "scale" the glyphicon *up* with `font-size`, and then scale it *down* using `transform:scale`. Scaling down should give you a better result.

There's also [`glyphicon-play`](http://glyphsearch.com/?library=glyphicons&query=triangle+play), which is already in the shape you want, without a need to transform. Use `font-size` for sizing, not `transform: scale` or you'll run into the same issue again. It only exists as a right-pointing arrow though.